# Java Abacus, Having trouble with the for loop to draw my counters

Tags: java, swing

As the title says, I'm having trouble with my Java code when it comes to finally drawing the counters on my abacus. the code compiles and runs but the counters are drawn starting from the first row instead of the top row. On top of this the counters do not stack in each column, one counter appears and moves up and down the column depending on which button is clicked which is correct but the counters should either be adding as I left click or subtracting as I right click.

I've spent a couple of hours on this and I'm sure it's something silly but my brain has stopped working and I cant think of any solutions.

Anyway, here is my code.

*AbacusPanel.java*

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.black);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    // we'll use Graphics2D for it's "draw" method -
    // neater than the Graphics "drawRect" suppled
    // (which you could also use)

    for (int i = 0;i<numCols;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<numRows;j++)
        {
            g2.draw(getRect(i,j));
        }
    }

    for(int thisCol= 0; thisCol < numCols; thisCol++)
    {
        for(int thisRow = 0; thisRow < numRows; thisRow++)
        {
            for(int counters=0; counters<=myAbacus.getNumCounters(thisCol); counters++)
            {
                Rectangle r2 = getRect(thisCol,myAbacus.getNumCounters(thisCol));
                g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g2.fillOval(r2.x, r2.y, r2.width, r2.height);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hopefully someone out there can point me in the right direction and sorry if any of this isn't formatted how you would like. This is my first question post and I have tried to make it easy on the eyes.

Comment: It would probably be easier to draw the grid as a series of horizontal and vertical lines rather than drawing a new rectangle for each box.

Comment: That is WAY too much code for StackOverflow. You need to state what exactly goes wrong, what you expected and give a couple of lines of code, preferrably code that has to do with the error directly.

Comment: Also, why do you have 2 main() functions?

Comment: I believe my error is contained within the nested 'for' loop at the bottom of AbacusPanel.java. I did not draw the grid, 90% of the AbacusPanel class was written by my lecturer, the AbacusModel class was written by myself as was the nested 'for' loop to paint the counters. What I expect to happen within this loop can be found at the top of my post :)

Comment: When you draw the placeholders for stones, you iterate over columns and then rows.  But when when draw the counters, you only iterate over columns and not rows.  Why not rows also?  And shouldn't the result of `getNumCounters()` take both column & row as inputs, since you're trying to get the number of counters per position on the mancala board, right?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have now included a for loop to iterate over the rows. I have been led to believe `getNumCounters()` is correctly written as in a previous task our AbacusModel.java file was tested. Now I have added the new for loop the counters appear in row 1 and all of the columns, as I click they either move up or down. if I click to subtract a counter when it is in the top row it does nothing which is correct, when I get to the bottom row and click to add a counter it throws an exception and won't allow me to add any counters in any columns until I have subtracted the counter.

Comment: Since it seemed to give you what you wanted, I stuck the comment in as an answer.  For continuing help here, if it's what you needed, accept away.  Homework questions are fine -- in response, people should ask you guiding questions, but not just "give you the answer".  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

When you draw the placeholders for stones, you iterate over columns and then rows. But when when draw the counters, you only iterate over columns and not rows. Why not rows also? And shouldn't the result of getNumCounters() take both column & row as inputs, since you're trying to get the number of counters per position on the mancala board, right?

In answer to your second question, I would have to believe that `getNumCounters()` would have to take both the row and column as inputs.  Since you've got two rows on the mancala board, and the number of stones is dependent upon both the column and whether it is in the first or second row, it wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Also, a third thing to think about.  In your rectangle, when you're drawing your counters, it seems would need to vary the position where they are -- it appears to me that each of your counters is going to stack on top of each other, so 20 counters will look no different than 1.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, After reading your responses I am almost there.